# How do I import custom time format values from Excel into R?

Tags: r, excel, time, xlconnect

I have an R script that loops through and reads multiple Excel spreadsheets into R using the XLConnect package.  The individual spreadsheets are combined into one large data frame, and then written out as a .csv file for further use in Excel.

```
newDf <- readWorksheetFromFile(filename,sheet=newid,header=TRUE,
                            startRow=1,endRow=17,startCol=1,endCol=6)
```

The Excel files have one column of time values in a custom format: HH:MM:SS.000

i.e.    00:18:06.264

When I open the resulting csv file, the values of this column appear as, for example,

```
1899-12-31 00:06:18
```

While I can easily remove the date (which I don't want) after the fact, my issue is that the decimal levels of the seconds are lost.  I need to keep them.  What is the correct way for me to keep the custom time format intact?

Thank you.

Comment: What "resulting csv file"? That should have produced an R data-object, not a csv file.

Comment: After all of the Excel sheets are read in and combined into one large data frame (using rbind), I use write.csv to make the result viewable in Excel again.  The time without the decimals is what I see when I open that.

Answer (score 0):

Use format.POSIXt

```
 write.csv( format( as.POSIXct("1899-12-31 00:06:18.123"), "%H:%M:%OS3"), file="")
"","x"
"1","00:06:19.123"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 0.2-10 **XLConnect** actually reads the milliseconds part of date/times in Excel. By default they are just not displayed in R. You may use `options(digits.secs = 6)` to display them accordingly in the R console.

With respect to 1899-12-31: Excel date/times are actually just numbers that represent the number of days since 1900-01-00 (yes, day 00! - see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm). Fractional days represent hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds. Times without dates are therefore just represented as fractional numbers 0.x which are translated to 1899-12-31 %HH:%MM:%SS.nnn since 1900-01-00 does not actually exist.
If you want to see the underlying (fractional) numbers when reading in the dates you may manually specify the column type to be `numeric` and use `forceConversion = TRUE` in the call to `readWorksheet`, e.g. `readWorksheet(..., colTypes = c(..., "numeric", ...), forceConversion = TRUE)`

With respect to the CSV export: When I use `write.csv2` the `POSIXct` column (resulting from a call to `readWorksheet`) seems to be exported including the milliseconds.